# Need help figuring out possible combinations in card game I am creating

Tags: probability, card-games

I am not sure if this is the right place to be asking the question, but hoping for some help. I created a simple card game for a D&D game I am running and I am trying to assign strength to each hand, I wanted to do this by knowing the possible combinations of each hand.

In this game, there is a deck of 45 cards, 5 suits each suit has cards value 1-9. Player has 5 cards in his hand, and the goal is to get cards in hand to equal a multiple of 5, i.e 5,10,15...,45. So I wanted to know how many possible ways are there for a player to get a hand equal to each of those multiples using the cards available in the deck? e.g. to get to a sum of 5 there is only 1 possible hand, you must have all 1's. However I do not know how to easily compute this for the values with many more combinations. Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: If all you are interested in is the rankings of the scoring hands... it should be clear that $Pr(X=5)=Pr(X=45)<Pr(X=10)=Pr(X=40)<Pr(X=15)=Pr(X=35)<\cdots < Pr(X=25)$ and this should be clear even without having calculated the exact values for each.

Comment: As [JMoravitz's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3780118/409) notes, my answer does not properly address your question. Please un-accept it so that I can delete it and hide my shame. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for are [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of the totals (but see the **Note** below). *Mathematica* has a convenient function for enumerating these: `IntegerPartitions[]`; specifically, using `IntegerPartitions[n,{5},{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}]` gives the partitions of $n$ into $5$ summands taken from the values $1$ to $9$.

The results are below. Note that $n$ and $(50-n)$ have the same number of partitions ($p$). I'll list the ones for the smaller number; to get the larger number, replace each entry by $10-n$. (So, partition $\{1,1,1,1,1\}$ for $5$ corresponds to partition $\{9,9,9,9,9\}$ for $45$.)

**Note:** These listed hands, and the values $p$, don't account for suit. If you consider the hand $\{6,1,1,1,1\}$ with a "Suit X" $6$ distinct from one with a "Suit Y" $6$, then there's more work to do. Nevertheless, it could be helpful to see what *numbers* are involved to get each total.

$$\begin{array}{ccl}
n & p & \\
\hline
5, 45 & 1 & \{1, 1, 1, 1, 1\} \\
\hline
10, 40  &  7 & \{6, 1, 1, 1, 1\}, \{5, 2, 1, 1, 1\}, \{4, 3, 1, 1, 1\}, \{4, 2, 2, 1, 1\}, \\
&&\{3, 3, 2, 1, 1\}, \{3, 2, 2, 2, 1\}, \{2, 2, 2, 2, 2\} \\
\hline
15, 35 & 28 & \{9, 3, 1, 1, 1\}, \{9, 2, 2, 1, 1\}, \{8, 4, 1, 1, 1\}, \{8, 3, 2, 1, 1\}, \\
&& \{8, 2, 2, 2, 1\}, \{7, 5, 1, 1, 1\}, \{7, 4, 2, 1, 1\}, \{7, 3, 3, 1, 
  1\}, \\
&& \{7, 3, 2, 2, 1\}, \{7, 2, 2, 2, 2\}, \{6, 6, 1, 1, 1\}, \{6, 5, 2, 1, 
  1\}, \\ && \{6, 4, 3, 1, 1\}, \{6, 4, 2, 2, 1\}, \{6, 3, 3, 2, 1\}, \{6, 3, 2, 2, 
  2\}, \\ && \{5, 5, 3, 1, 1\}, \{5, 5, 2, 2, 1\}, \{5, 4, 4, 1, 1\}, \{5, 4, 3, 2, 
  1\}, \\ && \{5, 4, 2, 2, 2\}, \{5, 3, 3, 3, 1\}, \{5, 3, 3, 2, 2\}, \{4, 4, 4, 2, 
  1\}, \\ && \{4, 4, 3, 3, 1\}, \{4, 4, 3, 2, 2\}, \{4, 3, 3, 3, 2\}, \{3, 3, 3, 3, 
  3\} \\
\hline
20, 30 & 57 & \{9, 8, 1, 1, 1\}, \{9, 7, 2, 1, 1\}, \{9, 6, 3, 1, 1\}, \{9, 6, 2, 2, 1\}, \\
&& \{9, 5, 4, 1, 1\}, \{9, 5, 3, 2, 1\}, \{9, 5, 2, 2, 2\}, \{9, 4, 4, 2, 1\}, \
\\ && \{9, 4, 3, 3, 1\}, \{9, 4, 3, 2, 2\}, \{9, 3, 3, 3, 2\}, \{8, 8, 2, 1, 1\}, \
\\ && \{8, 7, 3, 1, 1\}, \{8, 7, 2, 2, 1\}, \{8, 6, 4, 1, 1\}, \{8, 6, 3, 2, 1\}, \
\\ && \{8, 6, 2, 2, 2\}, \{8, 5, 5, 1, 1\}, \{8, 5, 4, 2, 1\}, \{8, 5, 3, 3, 1\}, \
\\ && \{8, 5, 3, 2, 2\}, \{8, 4, 4, 3, 1\}, \{8, 4, 4, 2, 2\}, \{8, 4, 3, 3, 2\}, \
\\ && \{8, 3, 3, 3, 3\}, \{7, 7, 4, 1, 1\}, \{7, 7, 3, 2, 1\}, \{7, 7, 2, 2, 2\}, \
\\ && \{7, 6, 5, 1, 1\}, \{7, 6, 4, 2, 1\}, \{7, 6, 3, 3, 1\}, \{7, 6, 3, 2, 2\}, \
\\ && \{7, 5, 5, 2, 1\}, \{7, 5, 4, 3, 1\}, \{7, 5, 4, 2, 2\}, \{7, 5, 3, 3, 2\}, \
\\ && \{7, 4, 4, 4, 1\}, \{7, 4, 4, 3, 2\}, \{7, 4, 3, 3, 3\}, \{6, 6, 6, 1, 1\}, \
\\ && \{6, 6, 5, 2, 1\}, \{6, 6, 4, 3, 1\}, \{6, 6, 4, 2, 2\}, \{6, 6, 3, 3, 2\}, \
\\ && \{6, 5, 5, 3, 1\}, \{6, 5, 5, 2, 2\}, \{6, 5, 4, 4, 1\}, \{6, 5, 4, 3, 2\}, \
\\ && \{6, 5, 3, 3, 3\}, \{6, 4, 4, 4, 2\}, \{6, 4, 4, 3, 3\}, \{5, 5, 5, 4, 1\}, \
\\ && \{5, 5, 5, 3, 2\}, \{5, 5, 4, 4, 2\}, \{5, 5, 4, 3, 3\}, \{5, 4, 4, 4, 3\}, \
\\ && \{4, 4, 4, 4, 4\} \\
\hline
25 & 73 & \{9, 9, 5, 1, 1\}, \{9, 9, 4, 2, 1\}, \{9, 9, 3, 3, 1\}, \{9, 9, 3, 2, 2\}, \
\\ &&\{9, 8, 6, 1, 1\}, \{9, 8, 5, 2, 1\}, \{9, 8, 4, 3, 1\}, \{9, 8, 4, 2, 2\}, \
\\ &&\{9, 8, 3, 3, 2\}, \{9, 7, 7, 1, 1\}, \{9, 7, 6, 2, 1\}, \{9, 7, 5, 3, 1\}, \
\\ &&\{9, 7, 5, 2, 2\}, \{9, 7, 4, 4, 1\}, \{9, 7, 4, 3, 2\}, \{9, 7, 3, 3, 3\}, \
\\ &&\{9, 6, 6, 3, 1\}, \{9, 6, 6, 2, 2\}, \{9, 6, 5, 4, 1\}, \{9, 6, 5, 3, 2\}, \
\\ &&\{9, 6, 4, 4, 2\}, \{9, 6, 4, 3, 3\}, \{9, 5, 5, 5, 1\}, \{9, 5, 5, 4, 2\}, \
\\ &&\{9, 5, 5, 3, 3\}, \{9, 5, 4, 4, 3\}, \{9, 4, 4, 4, 4\}, \{8, 8, 7, 1, 1\}, \
\\ &&\{8, 8, 6, 2, 1\}, \{8, 8, 5, 3, 1\}, \{8, 8, 5, 2, 2\}, \{8, 8, 4, 4, 1\}, \
\\ &&\{8, 8, 4, 3, 2\}, \{8, 8, 3, 3, 3\}, \{8, 7, 7, 2, 1\}, \{8, 7, 6, 3, 1\}, \
\\ &&\{8, 7, 6, 2, 2\}, \{8, 7, 5, 4, 1\}, \{8, 7, 5, 3, 2\}, \{8, 7, 4, 4, 2\}, \
\\ &&\{8, 7, 4, 3, 3\}, \{8, 6, 6, 4, 1\}, \{8, 6, 6, 3, 2\}, \{8, 6, 5, 5, 1\}, \
\\ &&\{8, 6, 5, 4, 2\}, \{8, 6, 5, 3, 3\}, \{8, 6, 4, 4, 3\}, \{8, 5, 5, 5, 2\}, \
\\ &&\{8, 5, 5, 4, 3\}, \{8, 5, 4, 4, 4\}, \{7, 7, 7, 3, 1\}, \{7, 7, 7, 2, 2\}, \
\\ &&\{7, 7, 6, 4, 1\}, \{7, 7, 6, 3, 2\}, \{7, 7, 5, 5, 1\}, \{7, 7, 5, 4, 2\}, \
\\ &&\{7, 7, 5, 3, 3\}, \{7, 7, 4, 4, 3\}, \{7, 6, 6, 5, 1\}, \{7, 6, 6, 4, 2\}, \
\\ &&\{7, 6, 6, 3, 3\}, \{7, 6, 5, 5, 2\}, \{7, 6, 5, 4, 3\}, \{7, 6, 4, 4, 4\}, \
\\ &&\{7, 5, 5, 5, 3\}, \{7, 5, 5, 4, 4\}, \{6, 6, 6, 6, 1\}, \{6, 6, 6, 5, 2\}, \
\\ &&\{6, 6, 6, 4, 3\}, \{6, 6, 5, 5, 3\}, \{6, 6, 5, 4, 4\}, \{6, 5, 5, 5, 4\}, \
\\ &&\{5, 5, 5, 5, 5\}
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 1):

Neither answer so far has successfully gotten to the probabilities of certain hand totals as having occurred and are unfairly biased towards hands which can only exist with large numbers of suits and against hands which can occur with many or few suits.

Writing a quick and dirty javascript can give the actual totals:

```
totalHands = function(target){
count=0;
for(a=1; a<46; a++){for(b=a+1;b<46;b++){for(c=b+1;c<46;c++){for(d=c+1;d<46;d++){for(e=d+1;e<46;e++){if((a-1)%9+(b-1)%9+(c-1)%9+(d-1)%9+(e-1)%9+5 == target){count++;}}}}}}
console.log(count)}
```

This counts the total number of hands (*suits relevant and order irrelevant*) for your desired sums.  Dividing by $\binom{45}{5}$ gives the probability of having gotten said sum.

The multiples of five in particular occur with the following frequencies and probabilities:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}\text{Sum}&\text{Frequency}&\text{Probability}\\\hline 5&1&\approx 8.2\times 10^{-7}\\10&1776&\approx 0.00145\\15&18251&\approx 0.0149\\20&59226&\approx 0.0485\\25&85751&\approx 0.07019\end{array}$$

The probabilities are symmetric with respect to $25$, so the probability of hitting a sum of $20$ is the same as hitting a sum of $30$ for instance and so on...

Comment: I got the same frequencies with different counting method. The OP should accept your solution.

Answer (score -1):

The number of ways to make a total of $t$ is the coefficient of $x^t$ in $$(x+x^2+\cdots+x^9)^5$$  Each factor represents one of the cards and the term within that factor represents the card.  Since we multiply the terms by adding exponents, the claim follows.

Now, we can just ask [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series%20%28x%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E4%2Bx%5E5%2Bx%5E6%2Bx%5E7%2Bx%5E8%2Bx%5E9%29%5E5&t=crmtb01) to multiply it out.  You just have to pick out the coefficients of terms of interesting degree.  For example, there are $976$ ways to make a total of $35$.

Comment: This ignores the fact that certain combinations are less likely to occur than other combinations.  It is far more likely to get a combination corresponding to one card each of $3,4,5,6,7$ than it is to get all $5$'s for instance.  Note that the cards are drawn without replacement.  You effectively counted the number of possibilities subject to the constraint that each suit occurs exactly once in each hand.

Comment: @JMoravitz I understood the question to ask for the number of combinations, not the probabilities.

Comment: it is implied that the OP is wishing to assign the strengths of each hand based on the relative rarity of encountering such a hand, as is done in poker (*while still conforming to the decision that only hands whose cards sum to a multiple of five are given any value and all other hands are worthless*).  The rarer the hand, the stronger.  While, yes, each hand can be categorized as one of the combinations you suggest, the relative rarity of the hands do not directly follow from this as this is unfairly biased towards hands which can only occur with large numbers of suits.

Comment: Imagine if you will a deck with a billion cards with value $1$, each of different suits, and two $5$'s, two $6$'s, and two $7$'s.  We draw two cards and look at their sum.  Sure, the only way to get a sum of $2$ is via $1+1$, and we have three ways of getting a sum of $12$, as $5+7, 6+6$ and $7+5$... seen by the coefficients of $(x+x^5+x^6+x^7)^2$, however getting a sum of $12$ is in fact incredibly rare.  This is extreme, sure, but it should highlight that looking only at certain aspects while avoiding taking probability correctly into consideration leads to incorrect results.